# Ubuntu 12.04 Update not working

Tags: installation, 12.04

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 through update manager, I had 11.04 as the previous version and everything goes fine from downloading the packages to restarting the system.

After restarting I found that there is no graphics related items in the installation and I cant able to move my trackpad in laptop. It shows a black screen with the desktop items but cant able to edit any items.

There is no menu items available in the desktop. Can any one help me in this.

Comment: I've just updated and got exactly the same problem as this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, I had exactly the same problem. I solved it by doing the following:

1. Boot into recovery mode.
2. Login and hit CTRL + ALT + 1
3. Type `sudo apt-get -f install`
4. Wait
5. Type `sudo shutdown -r now`
6. Wait
7. Profit!

Comment: Thanks for the answers, finally I got it using ubuntu recovery mode. I logged into recovery mode and run dpkg repair and it solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could include the graphics card of your computer. Are you able to select 'safe' mode in grub and do a sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade in a terminal. You can also try this when you drop to terminal by pressing ctrl+alt+f1 and log in there.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, finally I got it using ubuntu recovery mode. I logged into recovery mode and run dpkg repair and it solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to a text-based virtual console.

Have your machine connected to the Internet via an Ethernet cable.

Log in (you won't see anything happening on the screen as you type in your password, that's OK), and run these commands, by typing them in and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```